# Using the fonts from the pxfonts package with fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I've been using the `pxfonts` package to typeset my document since I liked the look of the text fonts.  I now have cause to use the `fontspec` package but now my favoured pxfonts don't load.  I'm getting the LaTeX warning that it is substituting "EU2/lmr/m/n" for "EU2/pxr/m/n".

I suspect the issue is that I'm too new to `fontspec` and don't know what I'm doing.  (Also using LuaLaTeX for the first time, but I think that's not so much the cause of the problem.)

What's the right way to load these "pxr" fonts using `fontspec`?... Clearly the `pxfonts` package is not it.  (I will have a very small amount of maths also, so I'll need the relevant maths fonts loaded too.)

Sorry if this is well trodden ground - I looked at other questions that arose when I searched for "pxfonts fontspec" but I couldn't make enough sense of what was being said to answer my question.

Comment: The `pxfonts` are not usable with `fontspec`.

Comment: Really?  So the act of loading `fontspec` now prevents me from using families of fonts that I could load using NFSS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pxfonts` is not “officially” deprecated, but it is so “typographically”, because there are several flaws in its design. Such flaws have brilliantly been fixed by Michael Sharpe who provided the package `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` instead.

However, `newpxtext` isn't compatible with `fontspec`, because it's based on “classical” 256 slot fonts.

You can obtain a very similar result using `newpxmath` for math fonts and a Palatino based text font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxmath} % math font is Palatino compatible
\usepackage[nomath]{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % or another Palatino OpenType clone
```

Comment: Thanks that's helpful.  I hadn't realized that TeX Gyre Pagella was a font that looked very similar to the pxr fonts.

Comment: @egreg Couldn't you load the TeX Gyre Pagella Unicode math font?

Comment: @JosephWright Of course, but it's not the same as `newpx`

Comment: Why use another font, if there is one specifically designed for use together with the main font? THe only thing I change is the `mathcal` and `mathscr` fonts, as i really don't like the ones in tex gyre pagella math. I take them from XITS Math instead